# How to Create Custom Cursor to Grab Colors of ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, color-picker

example of image of color grab application

[image]

Hello, I'd like to create an Android application to identify colors from an image. I'd like to use a custom cursor or a visual touch to let the user know the last touched area or simply to let the user know the picked color when they touch around the image. In other words, I'd like to create something like a magnifying glass cursor for the image. I couldn't think of a right name to put it so to make my explanation clear, please check the attached image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOA1p.jpg. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

have a look on this class, This is a custom ImageView. get your coordinate in onTouch() and from that coordinate you can get pixel color. feel free to Modify as per your use.

```
    <com.xbadal.views.MyImageView
            android:id="@+id/signature_canvas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />



public class MyImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
private final float TOLERANCE = 20;
private final int defaultWidth = 30;

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Context context;

private Paint paint;
private Point point;

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private int imageX;
private int imageY;

//Parameter Constructor
public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
}

// override onSizeChanged
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    Log.d(TAG, "onSizeChanged: " + h + "-" + w);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}

//Overriding onTouch
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    //Invert Matrix to get proper coordinate
    float[] eventXY = new float[]{x, y};
    Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
    getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);
    invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
    imageX = (int) eventXY[0];
    imageY = (int) eventXY[1];

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

            if (Math.abs(dx) >= TOLERANCE || Math.abs(dy) >= TOLERANCE) {
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    drawShape(canvas, mLastTouchX, mLastTouchY, defaultWidth);
}

//this method will detemine which shape to be drawn on the basis of ShapeId
public void drawShape(Canvas canvas, float x, float y, int width) {
    paint = new Paint();
    point = new Point();
    point.set((int) x, (int) y);


    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) this.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    if (x >= 0 && x < bitmap.getWidth() && y >= 0 && y < bitmap.getHeight()) {
        if (imageX >= 0 && imageX < bitmap.getWidth() && imageY >= 0 && imageY < bitmap.getHeight()) {
            int pixel = (bitmap.getPixel(imageX, imageY));
            int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
            int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
            int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
            int alpha = Color.alpha(pixel);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thank you for your answer, however is it possible if i'd like to show the color values on textviews? the textviews are on different activity..